# How to calculate score in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am very new to Laravel.

I have three tables named as applicants, questions,answers:

**Applicants**

```
id jobid name 
1   151  ABC
2   151  DEF
```

**Answers**

```
id qid jobid aaplicantid answer
1   21  151     1         1
2   22  151     1         0
3   21  151     2         1
4   22  151     2         1
```

**questions**

```
id jobid answer
21 151   1
22 151   1
```

Here I want calculate the % of score of the applicants based on questions ans answers table just assume for one job there two questions if the applicant answers match with question table answer then he will get 100% score if any one is not matched that much will be subtracted from the score.

I want the score should be divided like 
e.g : one job has 5 questions

```
score=>100/count(questions)=20 for each matched answer
```

for jobid 151 the applicants list should be as follows

```
id name score joid
1  ABC  50%   151
2  DEF  100%  151
```

And I am using the following query but its not giving expected results.

```
$apps=applicants::where('jobid','=',$jobId)->get();

    foreach($apps as $apo){
        $appid[]=$apo->id;
    }


    $score=answers::whereIn('appid',$appid)->where('jobid','=',$jobId)->get();

    $qid=array();
    foreach($score as $s){
        $qid[]=$s->qid;
    }
    $queid=questions::whereIn('id',$qid)->where('jobid','=',$jobId)->get();

    $calscore=100/(count($queid));


     $key = 0 ;   $finalscore = array();$sss = 0;
    for($n = 0; $n< count($queid); $n++) {
        foreach($queid as $que){
            $quei[]=$que->id;
            $weight[]=$que->weight;
            foreach ($score as $s){
                $qid[]=$s->qid;
                $sc[]=$s->answer;
                if($que->id==$s->qid){

                    if($weight==$sc){
                    $finalscore=$sss+$calscore;
                    $sss++;

                    }


                }
            }

            $key++;

        }
    }

    dd($finalscore);
```

and even I tried with join query its not giving the proper results. Is it possible with eloquent model?

Can somebody please help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use MySQL statement to get the percentage calculated.

You can create a view in your Laravel MySQL database.

```
SELECT *, (SUM(answer) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS results
    FROM answers
    LEFT JOIN applicants
        ON answers.applicantid = applicants.id
    GROUP BY answers.applicantid
```

It is also possible to call it from Laravel like:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw("
    SELECT *, (SUM(answer) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS results
        FROM answers
        LEFT JOIN applicants
            ON answers.applicantid = applicants.id
        GROUP BY answers.applicantid
    "))
```

as you can see it returns following results 50% and 100% as per your example:
[image]

**NOTE:**

1. I have created the MySQL statement on my local test environment and test it and it works.
   But since I do not have the code for your Laravel application, I have not test it in Laravel, so please do test it and let me know.
2. This is just example to demonstrate what you can get from MySQL, you can change and fine tune the statement to get the final results.